# What is the simple way to concatenate all strings on a list with a string in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, list, concatenation

I know how to do this, I just want a simpler way to implement this.

For example if I have the following list:

```
["This", "Is", "An", "Example"]
```

And the following string:

```
const str = "-abc"
```

The result I want is:

```
["This-abc", "Is-abc", "An-abc", "Example-abc"]
```

Comment: You will loop over the array and there are many functions to do that. `.map()` might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the map function to achieve this.

```
const arr = ["This", "Is", "An", "Example"];
const strToConcat = "-abc";
const formattedArr = arr.map(str => str+strToConcat);

console.log(formattedArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which will execute a function on each item in your array, and create a new one:

```js
const arr = ["This", "Is", "An", "Example"];
const str = "-abc";

const res = arr.map(x => x + str);

console.log(res);
```